# Drawing a rectangle shape with colored rounded border

Tags: android, drawable, shapes

How we can draw a rectangle shape like below image for setting as linear layout back ground?

[image]

is it possible to have this with xml shape or I must use a png image?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape is ready

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="14dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="#FFFFFF"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#42929d"
                />


        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="14dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="#FFFFFF"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="0dp"
                android:top="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="10dp"
                android:height="10dp"
                />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#42929d"
                />

        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Comment: very thanks @Biraj. I changed the size and padding values to 1 and it has not any changes. May you please explain what the size and padding tags do?